# Ho do I send a parameter to a subreport on a form using VBA in MS Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to do the following:
On a form with an embedded sub-report I want to send parameters to the sub-report which aren't linked to the form

I considered using the "ARG" section of the docmd.open but then how would I pass that to the sub-report?  Is there anyway to directly address the subreport?

I did try to link it to a field on the form using the Master/child relation but that seems to limit it to a single record

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can not send parameters directly to a subreport, beacuse it is embedded. OpenArgs is for opening a Main Form, not a Sub.

But you can refer directly from the subreport to the a Main Form Control, e.g.:

```
Me.Parent!ControlName
```

Or from parent to subreport:

```
Me!SubReport1.Report!ControlName
```

This nice table shows, how to refer to sub elements (just replace Form with Report) or to parent elements http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm

If you want to change data in the sub-element, then change the RecordSource in the sub by a event in the main.